# aws EMR cluster via cloud formation: not seeing hdfs on one

Tags: aws-cloudformation, emr

okay i have a EMR cluster which writes to HDFS and I am able to view the directory and see the files 
via

`hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/jobs`  - i am not seeing /user/hive or jobs directory in hadoop, but its supposed to be there.
[image]

I need to get in to the spark shell and perform sparql, so i created identical cluster with same vpc,security groups, and subnet id.

What i am supposed to see[image]

Why this is happending i am not sure but i think this might be it? Or any suggestions
Could this be something to with a stale rule?
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to upload a screenshot of your cluster configuration page from AWS EMR Console. What services did you choose when you spun your EMR Cluster from Console or Cloudformation? What sort of nodes did you choose ? what does "hdfs dfsadmin -report"  tell you ! (its a quick view of your cluster status) !

Comment: Please check if you have Hive listed as installed application on your EMR cluster. In CloudFormation, check this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html#cfn-emr-cluster-applications. You can also check using ps -ef | grep hive from within your cluster.